# Error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'istream'

Tags: c++, identifier

When I build my program and leave in my getTokens function within the header file, I get an error but when I take it out it builds fine. I'm trying to make a declaration for a function named getToken() within the header.

This is the error that I am getting.

tokens.h(26): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'istream'

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <istream>
#include <ostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>


class Tokens
{
public:
   enum TokenType {

   TEXT,
   LANGLE,
   RANGLE,
   SLASH,
   ID,
   EQ,
   QSTRING,
   OTHER,
   END,

   };

   TokenType getToken(istream*br, string&lexeme);

};
```

Comment: Missing `std::`. Voting to close as 'typographical error'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

istream and string is in the std namespace. You need to quality the type with the std namespace.

```
TokenType getToken(std::istream*br, std::string&lexeme);
```

It would also probably be better to use a reference to br rather than a pointer in terms of displaying intent.

```
TokenType getToken(std::istream &br, std::string &lexeme);
```

Just as a side note you wont need all of those includes. < istream> and < ostream> are included as part of < iostream>

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to figure out what to put in front of ::. Also I plan on using a while loop(br->good()) to read through the file so is it possible to use a reference instead?

Comment: Sorry, was interrupted for a moment.

Comment: Think of references as passing the actual object into the function.  Instead of -> you would use . I would go here if you want more info http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/references.html